# Treeview node in vc# for Auto Ellipsis property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a tree view control which has some nodes. I want Auto Ellipsis property to tree view node as like label control have. I did Google but not get relevant information or method to achieve this task.
I am using c# as a programing language and .net framework 3.5 as a platform.  I am making program in windows form not in WPF.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, that property doesn't exist. The `TreeView` control will display a horizontal scrollbar if the labels for any of the nodes are longer than the viewable area for the control.

The only option you have to replace this with an ellipsis is to owner-draw the control. But since you only want to change the text of the nodes, you can set the [`DrawMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawmode.aspx) to `OwnerDrawText` (rather than `OwnerDrawAll`), which significantly reduces the burden of owner drawing.

You can find sample code for owner drawing a `TreeView` control [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx).

Remember that the [`ClientRectangle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) of a control, including the `TreeView` control, will tell you the actual width of the control's client area. Use this to determine if the node label is too long, and whether or not it needs to be drawn with ellipses.

The [various overloads of the `TextRenderer.DrawText` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4eab953f.aspx) will allow you to draw the node labels in a way that resembles the way the native control draws itself (i.e., using GDI rather than GDI+). Passing an appropriate combination of [`TextFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags.aspx) will instruct the method to automatically trim text and replace it with an ellipsis.

Comment: @Awadhendra: It works great. What part didn't work for you? What code did you write?

Comment: I had set DrawMode property of treeview at design time.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer? Or did you just do the part that sounded easy?